# Key not working on laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have an ASUS laptop X54C. The q key has stopped working. Everything else is working. Things I have tried:
- took the key out and blowed air with my mouth. The area under the key wasn't dirty to begin with.
- device manager is not showing any abnormality
[image]
Could anyone help? Since this is a laptop buying a keyboard is not a solution as I want to continue to use this as a laptop.

Comment: When the key is off, what happens when you push down on the little prong that sticks up (that normally comes into contact with the key)?

Comment: Check if you are able to press **q** using **on screen keyboard**. If that works, you've got a hardware problem :/

Answer (score 0):

If the key mechanism under the key itself is not working, you could try using the end of paper clip to get under the key mechanism and lift out anything that could be blocking it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXP1_WjtBP0

Comment: yes that is what i have already tried